# Missing any configuration at Content Porter or WCM end which will help to export application data

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013

Looking for guidance in promoting contenttype/pagetype's configuration to higher environment using content porter.

Web publication has 20 different content type defined/created. Used content porter to promote content to SIT all content promoted to except content types n page type configuration.

Also, child publication is not persisting content type definition.

Can some help me out what special configurations/dependencies setting required at content porter or any other configuration at wcm which solved above problem?

Additional description based on given pointers to resolved issue.

Project Specific Export based on DXA1.2

Below tag is found in the export package index.xml

```
> <ApplicationIds>
>         <ApplicationId>SiteEdit</ApplicationId>
>       </ApplicationIds>
```

[image: Project Export]
However, we found 0-0-0.xml is missing in export package.

DXA 1.2
Below tag is found in the export package index.xml

```
<ApplicationIds>
      <ApplicationId>http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/vocabularies</ApplicationId>
    </ApplicationIds>
```

[image: Dxa 1.2 Export]

```
<PackageItem xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/ImportExport/Package/2013">
  <ApplicationDataCollection>
    <ApplicationData>
      <ApplicationId>http://www.sdl.com/tridion/SemanticMapping/vocabularies</ApplicationId>
      <TypeId></TypeId>
      <BinaryData>PAB2AG8AYwBhAGIAdQBsAGEAcgBpAGUAcwA+AA0ACgAgACAAPAB2AG8AYwBhAGIAdQBsAGEAcgB5ACAAcAByAGUAZgBpAHgAPQAiAHQAcgBpACIAIABuAGEAbQBlAD0AIgBoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAHcAdwB3AC4AcwBkAGwALgBjAG8AbQAvAHcAZQBiAC8AcwBjAGgAZQBtAGEAcwAvAGMAbwByAGUAIgAvAD4ADQAKACAAIAA8AHYAbwBjAGEAYgB1AGwAYQByAHkAIABwAHIAZQBmAGkAeAA9ACIAcwAiACAAbgBhAG0AZQA9ACIAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBzAGMAaABlAG0AYQAuAG8AcgBnAC8AIgAvAD4ADQAKADwALwB2AG8AYwBhAGIAdQBsAGEAcgBpAGUAcwA+AA==</BinaryData>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
    </ApplicationData>
  </ApplicationDataCollection>
</PackageItem>
```

Thanks ! Hiren

Comment: I'm rusty here, but Content Porter includes the ability to port "Application Data" (which is where Content Types are stored) between environments, this should be possible.

Comment: What does SIT mean?

Comment: System Integration Testing - America uses a different variant of DTAP :)

Comment: Hi Nuno, I have verified the export package do have content type details available in "Application Data" however while importing I just try to check item mappings and getting a warning "This intermediate package contains application data with the following identifier(s): http://www.sdl.com/tridion.SemanticMapping/typeof, which does not match any application data category defined on the target Content Manager. Because of this, Content Porter will not import this application data."

Comment: The App Data warnings are about DXA App Data used for DXA semantic mapping. Apparently, your Schema have such App Data. In that case, you should ensure you have the DXA App Data Definition XML file on your target machine. Doesn't explain why your XPM Content Types are not ported, though.

Comment: Check step #2 here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping me to crack this issue. Moreover, I have question why we can not inherit content type to child publication? Is it because those are publication properties? or do we need to make any other configuration?

Comment: Hi Nuno, post trying provided options other dependencies setting at content porter level below is the outcome.

Comment: Hi Nuno, Added additional observation to the issue. Please help us with your input.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue when porting from current environment (DXA working) to new environment. Copying the DXA Application Data Definition.xml to [tridion home]\config\ImportExport\ApplicationData solved the issue.