# Porting XPM Inline Editing Page Templates Settings to Another Environment

Tags: experience-manager, content-porter-2013

I'm getting ready for a content port and some changes were made to XPM settings in the dashboard settings menu: Settings>Inline Editing>Content Type Mappings>PublicationXYZ>Page Templates>PageTemplateXYZ

These changes were made to get XPM working with a new page template.  What is the best method to port these settings to another environment?  Is it included when you Content Port a Publication?

Comment: All the information I've found so far appears to indicate that these settings need to be manually duplicated across environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XPM Content Types are stored as Application Data attached to Publication. Normally, this Application Data is included if you use the CM Import/Export service to export/import the Publication (like Content Porter does).

Below is an example of the XPM Content Type Application Data (obtained from DXA Site Type Publication):

```
<configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit">
  <Publication xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" cloneComponentsInOwningPublication="false" clonePagesInOwningPublication="false">
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="Place" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for addresses and Google maps.">
        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4605" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-3290-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-329-2" />
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="Article" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for general articles/text on the site, also usable for th
ings like headers or teasers.">
        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4599" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-83-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-330-2" />
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="News Article" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for news articles.">
        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4725" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-83-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-1345-2" />
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="Image" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for images">
        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4597" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-4466-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-336-2" />
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="YouTube Video" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for YouTube videos">
        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4598" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-3284-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-1313-2" />
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="Content List" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for list of content for tabbed or accordion pages.">

        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4730" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-3270-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-329-2" />
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="Content Query" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for dynamic lists.">
        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4609" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-3276-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-329-2" />
      </ContentType>
      <ContentType xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" Title="Image List" InsertPosition="bottom" Description="DXA Content Type for thumbnail galleries.">
        <ContentTitle Type="prompt" />
        <Component xlink:href="tcm:1067-4727" />
        <ComponentTemplate xlink:href="tcm:1067-3279-32" />
        <Folder CanChange="yes" xlink:href="tcm:1067-329-2" />
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <PageTemplateSettings>
      <PageTemplate xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:1067-131-128" usePredefinedContentTypes="true">
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4605" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4599" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4725" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4597" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4598" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4730" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4609" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4727" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
      </PageTemplate>
      <PageTemplate xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:1067-135-128" usePredefinedContentTypes="true">
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4605" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4599" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4725" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4597" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4598" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4730" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4609" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4727" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
      </PageTemplate>
      <PageTemplate xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:1067-225-128" usePredefinedContentTypes="true">
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4605" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4599" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4725" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4597" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4598" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4730" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4609" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4727" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
      </PageTemplate>
      <PageTemplate xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:1067-108-128" usePredefinedContentTypes="true">
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4605" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4599" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4725" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4597" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4598" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4730" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4609" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
        <se:ContentType xlink:href="tcm:1067-4727" xmlns:se="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
      </PageTemplate>
    </PageTemplateSettings>
  </Publication>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I found a post from Nuno which claimed that as well here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15532/how-to-port-content-types-from-dev-to-sit-using-content-porter But I was more specificially wondering; does this also include the Content Type Mappings (to Page Templates) as configured through the Inline Editing Settings as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, it does. See example of the XPM Content Type App Data above.